# Django - Stripe API Integration Error - Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate

Tags: django, ssl, stripe-payments

So, testing in development worked accordingly, but moving to production yields the issue described in the title. I have contacted Stripe and they appear to be neglecting the problem.

The issue is intermittent, as if I refresh the page a few times, I can cause the error. It appears to be random.

- I am using Heroku to run a multi-tenant app with Django. Heroku-18 stack.
- I have a wildcard cert.
- TLS version is 1.2
- OpenSSL version is 1.1.1
- Python version 3.6.10
- Stripe version 2.41.1 (installed through pip and API version is up-to-date as well)

Error Log

```
Jan 13 21:58:36 app/web.1: raise error.APIConnectionError(msg, should_retry=should_retry)
Jan 13 21:58:36 app/web.1: stripe.error.APIConnectionError: Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate.  Please make sure that your
Jan 13 21:58:36 app/web.1: network is not intercepting certificates.  If this problem persists,
Jan 13 21:58:36 app/web.1: let us know at support@stripe.com.
```

In addition to these problems, the webhook I have fails from a 301 redirect. Not sure how my site is being redirected, but all instances of my webhook fail trying to connect to my site.

Honestly I am so stuck, so let me know if you need additional information to further help me.

Comment: You could write into Support ( https://support.stripe.com/contact/email ) but this sounds like you may be missing some certs from your environment - this is probably a server configuration issue.  But write into Support so they can look into the details for you.

Comment: Yeah I wrote into support. All they said were to check my versions lol. In terms of missing certs from my environment,  what do you mean? I have a wildcard cert attached to the Heroku instance and I have the most up to date AWS cert for my RDS instance.

Comment: It's not your HTTPS certs, it's the TLS certificate bundle on your server, or possibly your server's outbound traffic to Stripe is being fiddled with in some way.

Comment: Stripe had me try their reachability script on my Heroku instance and everything was fine. Stripe then proceeded to say they had never seen the error "SSL Uninitialized" and pointed to Heroku to help me. Heroku basically said its outside their jurisdiction. However, Stripe mentioned checking to see if we could access external sources from within Python. Heroku said it might be worth checking library versions....

Comment: Is there anything I can do to manage the TLS certs on the server? Heroku stated that they do not have a proxy and do not mess with outgoing traffic as seen by running the stripe reachability script.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to suggest here.  Stripe on Heroku should work just fine, so it's most likely a configuration or version issue as they suggest.  It's unfortunately probably not something anyone can help you with as it's likely going to take a bunch of digging into your system to understand.  You should though log the whole error and its stack trace as a starting point.

Comment: I was able to show extra logging and get a full stack trace. It seems there is intermittent changes when it prints the requestClient object which makes me wonder if this is related to some time of threading problem. In regards to versioning, I don't understand what would be the issue since Heroku-18 only supports 3 different versions of Python. 3.7.6 doesn't solve the problem. Stripe's package dependencies looks fine and I shouldn't have to worry about those. Hopefully they can help me further after they go through the stacktrace.